# writing back changed csv values in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am having some problems writing back the values that I want to the output csv file. My intention is to get the values of the csv file and change those values that are equal to 'Never-worked' or 'Without-pay' to being 'Not-working'. My code successfully fulfills this, however, it does not write it back to the csv file appropriately, meaning the changed values are not written back, but the file remains the same as the original. What am I doing wrong?

```
import csv

infile = open('income.csv','rb')
outfile = open('income-new.csv', 'wb')

def changeOccupation(cell):
    if (cell.lower() == 'never-worked' or cell.lower() == 'without-pay'):
        cell = 'Not-working'
        print(cell)

#go trough each line of the file
for line in infile:
    row = line.split(',')
    for cell in row:
        changeOccupation(cell)

    #print(row)

    outfile.write(','.join(row))

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retun the new value and wright the changed row pack:

```
def changeOccupation(cell):
    if (cell.lower() == 'never-worked' or cell.lower() == 'without-pay'):
        return 'Not-working'
    return cell

#go trough each line of the file
for line in infile:
    row = line.split(',')
    new_row = [changeOccupation(cell) for cell in row]       
    outfile.write(','.join(new_row))
```